# FullCalendar: Can I get start time related to coordinates of an EventClick?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am writing an Appointment Scheduling module using FullCalendar.
Thus, the main goal is to utilize two types of events:

- Appointment -- for an actual scheduled appointment
- Available   -- for an available timeslot

I modified FullCalendar so that Appointment type events are rendered a certain color, and Available type events another color.

The main goal is to allow someone to
 - view available timeslots
 - select all or part of that timeslot to schedule an Appointment type event
 - ability to disallow overlapping Appointments
 - do nothing anytime a user clicks outside an Available timeslot

The Available events are rendered first, then the Appointment type events last.
I modified fullcalendar so that overlapping events do not display side-by-side - but rather the Appointment events lay on top of the Available events.

Inside the eventClick I am first checking the event type.
If it is an Appointment event, then i would like to just edit that selected Appointment event.

If it is an Available event, then i would like to create a new Appointment type event.

If it is just a dayClick event, then ignore

Originally, i would call function:  CreateEvent on Select
and call UpdateClick on eventClick
like this:

```
select : CreateEvent,
eventClick : UpdateClick,
```

Those functions popup a dialog where they can either add or edit an event.
Since I only want them to be able to schedule an Appointment inside an existing Available event slot, I thought maybe i could call the same procedures like below:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

if (calEvent.type=='AVAILABLE') {
 CreateEvent;      // schedule new appt.
} else if (calEvent.type=='APPOINTMENT') {

 UpdateClick;   // edit existing appt.
}
```

}

The problem with that code is that the routine:  CreateEvent requires a start and end time.

```
    function CreateEvent(start, end, allDay) {
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
 var id = $(formStart + formEnd);

 $(id).dialog( {
  title : 'Create',
  modal : true,
  autoOpen : true,
  width : "340px",
  resizable : false,
  close : function(event, ui) {
   $(id).html('');
  },
  buttons : {
   "Ok" : function() {
    title = document.getElementById('titleId').value;

    $(id).dialog("close");
    ev = {
     title : title,
     start : start.getTime() / 1000,
     end : end.getTime() / 1000,
     allDay : allDay
    };
    if (!title) {
     return;
    }
    serverSave(ev);
   },
   "Cancel" : function() {
    $(id).dialog("close");
   }
  }
 });}
```

I do not want to use the Event Start and Event End, since that will be the full available time-slot.
When scheduling an appointment, they may only use part of that Available timeslot.

So, do you know how to convert the actual mouse pointer Y coordinate to a starting time for the appointment?

And/Or

Do you see a much easier way to handle this type of appointment scheduling with FullCalendar?

Thanks

Comment: I think i found an alternative solution to this issue.  When a user clicks on an available timeslot, my dialog box will give them time options within that available slot.  They can select the time range and then the Appointment type event will be created.  Sorry this question maybe became a little over-detailed.  Thanks again for anyone who already has looked into this.

Comment: Could you post your solution in your answers ? It will be helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the jsEvent contains a lot of information including the coordinates of the click event within the calendar slot. (See [eventClick documentation about PageX & pageY](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/)) where it talks about the coordinates.

Another solution that comes to mind would be to switch to a day view so it would be easier to select/see a time that is available. This switch could be handled by a modal-type pop-up even.

Hope that helps.